# positioning xAxis and yAxis with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

What I have works but I am wondering if there is a better way.

I have [this](http://www.d3geometry.com/functions?uid=333333) page as my working example.  The source code is [here](https://github.com/dagda1/d3-geometry/blob/master/app/js/components/function-plot.js) and this question deals specifically drawing x axis and y axis with positive and negative values.

I have a `drawAxes` method that looks like this:

```
  drawAxes(data) {
    const xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(this.xScale);

    const yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .orient('left')
            .scale(this.yScale);

    const dimensions = this.getDimensions();

    this.xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.x));

    const minY = d3.min(data, (d) => d.y);
    const maxY = d3.max(data, (d) => d.y);

    const nonNegativeXAxis = minY >= 0 && maxY >= 0;
    const positiveAndNegativeXAxis = minY < 0 && maxY > 0;

    let yScaleDomain, xAxisPosition;

    if(nonNegativeXAxis) {
      yScaleDomain = [0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.y)];
    }  else {
      yScaleDomain = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.y);
    }

    this.yScale.domain(yScaleDomain);

    const findZeroTick = (data) => {
      return data === 0;
    };

    this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis y-axis')
      .style('visibility', 'hidden')
      .call(yAxis);

    if(nonNegativeXAxis) {
      yScaleDomain = [0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.y)];
      xAxisPosition = dimensions.height;
    } else if(positiveAndNegativeXAxis) {
      xAxisPosition = this.svg.selectAll(".tick").filter(findZeroTick).map((tick) => {
        return d3.transform(d3.select(tick[0]).attr('transform')).translate[1];
      });
    } else {
      yScaleDomain = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.y);
      xAxisPosition = 0;
    }

    this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis x-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${xAxisPosition})`)
      .call(xAxis);

    d3.select('.y-axis').remove();

    const minX = d3.min(data, (d) => d.x);
    const maxX = d3.max(data, (d) => d.y);

    const positiveXOnly = minX > 0 && maxX > 0;
    const negativeXOnly = minX < 0 && maxX < 0;

    let yAxisPosition;

    if(positiveXOnly) {
      yAxisPosition = 0;
    } else if(negativeXOnly) {
      yAxisPosition = dimensions.width;
    } else {
      yAxisPosition = this.svg.selectAll(".x-axis .tick").filter(findZeroTick).map((tick) => {
        return d3.transform(d3.select(tick[0]).attr('transform')).translate[0];
      });
    }

    this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis y-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${yAxisPosition}, 0)`)
      .call(yAxis);
  }
```

WHat I found great difficulty in was positioning the y axis x axis at 0 on the opposite axis.

How I did this was to first of all draw the y axis but keep it hidden:

```
this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis y-axis')
  .style('visibility', 'hidden')
  .call(yAxis);
```

I then found the position of 0 on the y axis by selecting all the ticks and finding the y coordinate of the 0 tick, I use this value to position the x axis:

```
const findZeroTick = (data) => {
  return data === 0;
};

xAxisPosition = this.svg.selectAll(".tick").filter(findZeroTick).map((tick) => {
  return d3.transform(d3.select(tick[0]).attr('transform')).translate[1];
});

this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis x-axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${xAxisPosition})`)
  .call(xAxis);
```

To position the yAxis, I first of all remove the yAxis and then do a similar calculation by selecting all the ticks on the x-axis and then adding the yAxis again with and using the retrieved value to position the yAxis:

```
d3.select('.y-axis').remove();

yAxisPosition = this.svg.selectAll(".x-axis .tick").filter(findZeroTick).map((tick) => {
  return d3.transform(d3.select(tick[0]).attr('transform')).translate[0];
});

this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis y-axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${yAxisPosition}, 0)`)
  .call(yAxis);
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result or failing that, can I move the axis without having to remove it and re-add it?

Comment: By the way, your plot is wrong if you set a number<=0 as right x range element.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your linear scale has a domain and a range you can use it to get the pixel value of any domain value. For example, to get the pixel of point (0 , 0) you would ask `xScale(0)` and `yScale(0)`.

If these values lie outside the defined range (read: svg canvas dimensions in pixels), you know that the Y-axis should be on the far left or right respectively (min or max range plus margin).

Comment: Yes but the problem is pinning down where 0 is on the axis

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Depending on the user input on the page http://www.d3geometry.com/functions?uid=333333, the origin could be in any number of different places.  It is not always at the far left or far right.  Or in the case of the y axis top or bottom, it can be anywhere inbetween

Comment: xScale(0) and yScale(0) do not return the correct values

Comment: xScale and yScale is what D3 uses to draw all geometry. If you tell it to draw a point at (0, 0) then it actually calls the scale functions to determine the pixel position.

Comment: xScale(0) is not the position of the 0 tick on the xAxis axis, the same goes for yScale(0)

Comment: If your tick is on (0, 0) of your domain, then it should be drawn on top of pixel with offset scaleX(0) and scaleY(0). If that's not working for you, you probably change your range or domain somewhere. Consider this minimal example: http://jsbin.com/kicovokoku/edit?html,console,output . The console output shows you the x-pixel values of -100, 0 and 100 respectively. These are also the x-coordinates of the respective ticks. The pixel coordinates are count from top left of the SVG element raising to bottom right by the way.